# What does '_' mean in python

Tags: python

I was reading a Python textbook, and this was in one of the examples. So I wonder what '_' means in something like this:

```
a = [[] for _ in xrange(10)]
```

> > > range(2,10,2)
> > >       [2, 4, 6, 8]
> > >
> > > type(_)

Comment: It's just a name for a variable you don't care about. With "don't care about" I mean, that you're not interested in the value of the variable so there's no need to use a meaningful name.

Comment: It is basically an 'ignore' symbol to a variable

Comment: Actually I want to ask type(_).